# How to close all toastr messages on click an anchor using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, toastr

I use [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) to toast notifications in my page. How can I close all open messages if a link is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you have the the `toastr` global object defined.

```
console.log(!!window.toastr);
```

if you have it you can use `toastr.clear();`

```
$('a.myLinkClass').click(function() {
   window.toastr.clear();
});
```